# Did the Nostalgia Critic accurately predict "Transformers: The Last Knight"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-the-last-knight

In [*Transformers: The Last Knight* NON-Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctembQrH_0k), The Nostalgia Critic proposes that the Transformers movies have become so predictable that he can review *The Last Knight* without even watching it.

**How accurate were the Nostalgia Critic's predictions about *Transformers: The Last Knight*?**

---

To summarize, some of the predictions from his "review" included:

- Majority of the film set in present day, with only the first few opening minutes and brief flashbacks set in the past.
- Mark Wahlberg's character has an intro where he gets used to Transformers in his daily life.
- Comic relief characters throughout large parts of the film making immature sex jokes.
- Supporting cast of children includes a good-looking outcast, a geeky character who dies, and an intelligent hot chick with glasses.
- Returning supporting cast: Either Josh Duhamel, John Turturro, Stanley Tucci, Shia Labeouf, or all of the above.
- Seemingly important government official in a suit played by a celebrity actor who reads exposition and is part of a government coverup.
- Optimus Prime spends most of the film either out of commission or looking for something from his homeworld so that humans can take the leading role.
- An evil force comes to Earth looking for a vaguely defined "power energy thing" which can destroy the world.
- Megatron plays a secondary role to the main villain, a human-looking machine riding a giant ship that's going to blow up the world and "does something on the moon".
- Movie will make audience think Optimus Prime is a bad guy before revealing he is brainwashed or being controlled by the villain.
- One of the transformers will seemingly die, before coming back to life or being revived.
- Several scenes of asking whether humanity is worth saving.
- Man human characters learn "something about letting go, yet somehow being closer."
- "The bad guy will be destroyed, but some villainous element, usually Megatron, will escape for a sequel."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> - Majority of the film set in present day, with only the first few opening minutes and brief flashbacks set in the past.

True. The movie starts in medieval times, and flashes back a few times, but takes place in an unidentified current-ish year.

> - Mark Wahlberg's character has an intro where he gets used to Transformers in his daily life.

Mostly false. The movie's first scene with Cade Yeager deals with him trying to rescue two injured Transformers and some children. From there, we move to Cade's home life, where he is dealing with Autobots in his daily life.

> Comic relief characters throughout large parts of the film making immature sex jokes.

False. The comic relief in this movie is mostly Cogman, and his snark and self-described sociopathy. There are no scenes like swinging construction balls, Decepticons humping legs, or Autobots peeing on things.

> - Supporting cast of children includes a good-looking outcast, a geeky character who dies, and an intelligent hot chick with glasses.

Mostly false. While the marketing campaign did seem to heavily feature the children, most of the children only feature in the first 15-20 minutes, and are never seen again. Izabella, the teenage girl continues through the movie in a non-essential role. She does not have glasses. Vivian, an attractive and intelligent adult female does not have glasses (that I recall - someone may correct me here). None of the children die. Hopkins' character dies, but is not "geeky".

> - Returning supporting cast: Either Josh Duhamel, John Turturro, Stanley Tucci, Shia Labeouf, or all of the above.

Half-true. Duhamel returns in a featured role. Turturro shows up briefly, but is relegated to a few scenes where he is on the phone. Labeouf does not appear, with Labeouf's character implied to be dead. Stanley Tucci appears briefly as Merlin - but does not reprise his role as Joshua Joyce from *Age of Extinction*.

> - Celebrity actor in a suit reading exposition and is part of a government coverup.

True. I guess? I'm not really sure what this means. Anthony Hopkins' character handles the exposition, and wears a suit, but is not an in-universe celebrity actor.

> - Optimus Prime spends most of the film either out of commission or 
>     looking for something from his homeworld.

True. Optimus barely appears for half the movie. He is searching for a staff.

> - An evil force comes to Earth looking for a vaguely defined "power energy thing" which can destroy the world.

True enough. Sort of. Quintessa and Optimus are looking for a powerful staff that can be used to destroy Unicron - which happens to be Earth.

> - Megatron plays a secondary role to the main villain, a human-looking machine riding a giant ship that's going to blow up the world and "does something on the moon".

Part-true. Megatron plays a secondary role, but is barely even a villain here. The main villain is human-looking-ish. She does not ride a giant ship, but one does feature. The ship is not a massive weapon. The main villain does *however* come traveling on a massive planet with intentions of destroying Earth. It is unclear exactly what role the planet may take in the destruction itself. Nothing happens on the moon.

> - Movie will make audience think Optimus Prime is a bad guy before revealing he is brainwashed or being controlled by the villain.

Mostly false. Optimus is turned into a bad guy pretty much in his first scene. There is no big reveal.

> - One of the transformers will seemingly die, before coming back to life or being revived.

Mostly false. Bumblebee is blasted apart in his first scene in the movie, and immediately reassembles himself automatically. Only the bad guys thought they had defeated Bumblebee, and only for a few seconds. Nobody is revived or returns from being presumed dead.

> - Several scenes of asking whether humanity is worth saving.

False. The closest is Megatron saying that Optimus betrayed his own kind for siding with the humans.

> - Man human characters learn "something about letting go, yet somehow being closer."

I guess? Cade realizes that he's shut himself off from the world maybe a little too much, and decides to act on his attraction to Victoria.

> - "The bad guy will be destroyed, but some villainous element, usually Megatron, will escape for a sequel."

True. Quintessa is defeated, but is revealed to have survived in the movie's mid-credit scene.

Comment: Cade Edwards? Cade Yeager.

Comment: Amazing answer. To clarify, "celebrity actor" wasn't referring to an in-universe celebrity, so that one would be true.

Comment: I thought Stanley Tucci WAS in this movie, just playing a different part than the last movie.  Haven't seen it, but had heard that in several reviews.

Comment: @eshier apparently, *tucci* was, and just completely unrecognizable in makeup. he's got a 2 minute role as another character. updating.